Low GPU utilization using torch_geometric.nn.Module
I've been experimenting with Graph Convolutional Networks and built the model below. However, I've noticed that despite running on cuda:0, the GPU utilization is minimal (only 400MB out of 16GB) while the CPU seems to be doing most of the work.
class MultiGraphGNN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_node_features, num_edge_features, protein_features_dim):
        super(MultiGraphGNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.graph1_conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 16)
        self.graph1_conv2 = GCNConv(16, 32)

        self.graph2_conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 16)
        self.graph2_conv2 = GCNConv(16, 32)

        self.graph3_conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 16)
        self.graph3_conv2 = GCNConv(16, 32)

        self.graph4_conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, 32)
        self.graph4_conv2 = GCNConv(32, 64)
        self.graph4_conv3 = GCNConv(64, 128)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32 * 3 + 128 + protein_features_dim, 128)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 1)

    def forward(self, data1, data2, data3, data4, protein_features):
        x1 = F.relu(self.graph1_conv1(data1.x, data1.edge_index))
        x1 = global_mean_pool(F.relu(self.graph1_conv2(x1, data1.edge_index)), data1.batch)

        x2 = F.relu(self.graph2_conv1(data2.x, data2.edge_index))
        x2 = global_mean_pool(F.relu(self.graph2_conv2(x2, data2.edge_index)), data2.batch)

        x3 = F.relu(self.graph3_conv1(data3.x, data3.edge_index))
        x3 = global_mean_pool(F.relu(self.graph3_conv2(x3, data3.edge_index)), data3.batch)

        x4 = F.relu(self.graph4_conv1(data4.x, data4.edge_index))
        x4 = F.relu(self.graph4_conv2(x4, data4.edge_index))
        x4 = global_mean_pool(F.relu(self.graph4_conv3(x4, data4.edge_index)), data4.batch)

        combined = torch.cat((x1, x2, x3, x4, protein_features), dim=1)

        combined = F.relu(self.fc1(combined))
        combined = F.relu(self.fc2(combined))
        return torch.sigmoid(self.fc3(combined))

model = MultiGraphGNN(num_node_features=5, num_edge_features=3, protein_features_dim=3)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model.to(device)
print(model)

And here is my dataset and training loop
class MoleculeGraphDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, one_hot_encoded, device, transform=None, pre_transform=None):
        super(MoleculeGraphDataset, self).__init__(None, transform, pre_transform)
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.one_hot_encoded = one_hot_encoded
        self.device = device

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        row = self.dataframe.iloc[idx]
        graphs = [row[f'buildingblock{i}_smiles'] for i in range(1, 4)] + [row['molecule_smiles']]
        one_hot = torch.tensor(self.one_hot_encoded[idx], dtype=torch.float, device=self.device)
        target = torch.tensor([row['binds']], dtype=torch.float, device=self.device)
        return (*graphs, one_hot, target)

def collate_fn(batch):
    transposed = list(zip(*batch))
    graphs = [Batch.from_data_list(graph_list) for graph_list in transposed[:4]]    
    one_hot_vectors = torch.stack(transposed[4], dim=0)
    targets = torch.stack(transposed[5], dim=0)
    
    return (*graphs, one_hot_vectors, targets)

train_dataset = MoleculeGraphDataset(train_df, one_hot_encoded_train, device)
val_dataset = MoleculeGraphDataset(val_df, one_hot_encoded_val, device)
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10000, shuffle=True, collate_fn=collate_fn)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=10000, shuffle=False, collate_fn=collate_fn)

def train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer, num_epochs=25):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        model.train()
        running_loss = 0.0

        for data1, data2, data3, data4, one_hot, targets in train_loader:
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            outputs = model(data1, data2, data3, data4, one_hot)
            loss = criterion(outputs, targets)


            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss += loss.item() * data1.size(0)

        epoch_loss = running_loss / len(train_loader.dataset)

        val_loss = 0.0
        model.eval()  
        with torch.no_grad():
            for data1, data2, data3, data4, one_hot, targets in val_loader:
                outputs = model(data1, data2, data3, data4, one_hot)
                loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
                val_loss += loss.item() * data1.size(0)

            val_loss /= len(val_loader.dataset)

        print(f'Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}, Validation Loss: {val_loss:.4f}')

    print('Training complete')

train_model(model, train_loader, val_loader, criterion, optimizer)

I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on why the GPU usage is so low and how I might better optimize my setup. I'm sorry if the code isn't as polished — I'm still exploring this area and learning as I go!
Thank you all in advance!
I've tried setting num_workers = 4 and pin_memory = True but nothing changed, my GPU usage remains minimal

Have you ensured that your tensors and objects are actually on cuda:0 device? If not, shift them there using torch.Tensor.to() or torch.to().

The model and all tensors (as can be seen in the code provided) was moved to cuda. Everything is on cuda, however most of the work is done by the cpu. This could very well be a pyg specific quirk but I found no mention of it so far
